# Installing kube-state-metrics into an existing cluster on GCE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

Trying to follow the tutorial on the offical GitHub: https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics

I manages to make the container but after i want to apply using `kubectl apply -f kubernetes` i get the following error message:

```
ction refused
unable to recognize "kubernetes/kube-state-metrics-cluster-role.yaml": Get http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection re
fused
unable to recognize "kubernetes/kube-state-metrics-deployment.yaml": Get http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refu
sed
unable to recognize "kubernetes/kube-state-metrics-role-binding.yaml": Get http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection re
fused
unable to recognize "kubernetes/kube-state-metrics-role.yaml": Get http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
unable to recognize "kubernetes/kube-state-metrics-service-account.yaml": Get http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection
 refused

Anyone knows what this is about?
Clusters Master Version is 1.10.11-gke.1
```

Comment: Seems that `api-server` admission and validation checking rejected applying of provided resources. Also it could be networking issue or broken kubectl utility configuration. In rare cases. your k8s user identity hasn't permissions for applying resources.

Comment: I will recommend you to check `stackdriver` instead of `kube-state-metrics` if you're using GKE.